# Android swipe right to left to expand fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, uigesturerecognizer

Hi guys I am an android beginner. I want to make an fragment at the right edge of the main layout and it could be expanded/collapsed by swiping from right to left/left to right (please watch sort video below).

https://youtube.com/shorts/HKOvfDVS03M?feature=share

My problem is I could not know how I can start implementing since I'm new to android. Please help to give a sample code. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same using navigation drawer. Navigation drawer is menu or layout which slides from edges of the screen. As you are a beginner you need to learn the concepts first. So, try to learn navigation drawer first. As per suggestion you can watch below video.

[Navigation drawer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGcMLu1GJEc)

As you complete the video you will know what navigation drawer is and how to implement it. Now, as you mentioned in your video it's a calculator. So, drawer is given specific height and width as well as it is placed below the calculating screen. SO, I assume that you know basics.

Using relative layout and it's property You can use

```
...
android:layout_below = "calculating_screen"
...
```

This will place your drawer below the screen and you can specify `android:layout_height =match_parent" in your drawer file to cover the remaining screen. And then after specifying width you just need to adjust the gravity. you just need to change the gravity line.

```
...
GravityCompat.END
...
```

from

```
...
GravityCompat.START
...
```

`GravityCompat.START` allows drawer to expand from left-right. If you want right-left then use `GravityCompat.END`.